# iOS 8.3 Emoji Keyboard dont scroll

Tags: ios, scroll, emoji

i have some `UISearchBars` and one `UITextView` in the App on different Screens.

With iOS 8.3 Emoji Keyboard should be scrollable but it isnt in any of the Screens.
I tried to find some similarity or removed the `UIKeyboardWillShow - and -HideNotification` from my Controller but nothing changed.

Thats all what i do with the TextView in Code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
... some code ...
[self.textView setFont:...];
[self.textView setTextContainerInset:...];
[self.textView setText:...];
... some code ...
}

- (void)updateView
{
... some code ...
[self.textView setEditable:YES];
... some code ...
}


#pragma mark - TEXTVIEW DELEGATE

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    ... some code ...
    return changedText.length <= maxLength;
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    ... some code ...
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:range];
    ... some code ...
}
```

There are no GestureRecognizers in this Controller or in any SuperController.

There is also an ScrollViewDelegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self.refreshControl scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    [self.refreshControl scrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView];
}
```

No custom Keyboard.

Even if i add a new UITextView to my UIWindow on top of the NavigationController.view it wont work.

Somebody any idea?

Comment: 8.3 Emoji keyboard scrolls fine when UISearchBar has focus.  Something in your app must be affecting gestures, responder chain, but without code, all anyone can do is suggest possibilities.

Comment: possibilities is all i need because like you said: "Something in the App". Its way too much code to post it all there because i even dont know where to start to search.

Comment: And: There are no Gesture Recognizers.

Comment: Doing anything with inputViews?  Custom keyboards? ScrollViewDelegate?

Comment: What inputViews do you mean?

Comment: It has to do with (customizing) the keyboard and accessory views.  But you're mentioning navigationController.view and adding textView to UIWindow.  There's a problem in the code we don't see.  You'll need to share more of it, or write a sample project that demonstrates the issue and share it on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Bug.
I overwrote the delaysContentTouches for all UIScrollViews like this:

```
#import "UIScrollView+Extension.h"

@implementation UIScrollView (Extension)

- (BOOL)delaysContentTouches
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Now i just kicked it out and it works!!!
Thank you all for your Effort.